# Eclipse doesn't find the main class during exporting of project as executable jar

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a feeling it will be a trivial question, but it's making me bash my head against a wall.

I was in need of a Java program that could record audio as fast as one could do it. I searched for some pre-existing code, I found [this](https://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-develop-a-sound-recorder-program-in-java-swing) and made exactly one alteration to the code: I ensured the first thing after having created the GUI would be for Java itself to press the record button.

Below the modified main method, found in the class `SwingSoundRecorder`:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SwingSoundRecorder GUI = null;
                GUI = new SwingSoundRecorder();
                GUI.setVisible(true);
                
                // This line ensures the GUI will start recording immediately
                GUI.buttonPlay.doClick();
            }
        });
    }
```

Done this, I tried to export it as a Java executable. Since I use Eclipse, I thought it would be very easy: one just has to specify where you want the .jar file and what is the main class.

Well, apparently Java do not recognize the `SwingSoundRecorder` as having a main method to use. And I *really* do not understand why.

Any idea? Any help?

---

Edit: complete code of all four classes involved, as @anish sharma rightly wanted:

```
public class SwingSoundRecorder extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2747541100831140840L;
    private JButton buttonRecord = new JButton("Record");
    private JButton buttonPlay = new JButton("Play");
    private JLabel labelRecordTime = new JLabel("Record Time: 00:00:00");

    private SoundRecordingUtil recorder = new SoundRecordingUtil();
    private AudioPlayer player = new AudioPlayer();
    private Thread playbackThread;
    private RecordTimer timer;

    private boolean isRecording = false;
    private boolean isPlaying = false;

    private String saveFilePath;

    // Icons used for buttons
    private ImageIcon iconRecord = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
            "/net/codejava/sound/images/Record.gif"));
    private ImageIcon iconStop = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
            "/net/codejava/sound/images/Stop.gif"));
    private ImageIcon iconPlay = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(
            "/net/codejava/sound/images/Play.gif"));
    

    /**
     * launch the program
     * 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SwingSoundRecorder GUI = null;
                GUI = new SwingSoundRecorder();
                GUI.setVisible(true);
                
                // This line ensures the GUI will start recording immediately
                GUI.buttonPlay.doClick();
            }
        });
    }

    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    

    public SwingSoundRecorder() {
        super("Swing Sound Recorder");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        buttonRecord.setFont(new Font("Sans", Font.BOLD, 14));
        buttonRecord.setIcon(iconRecord);
        buttonPlay.setFont(new Font("Sans", Font.BOLD, 14));
        buttonPlay.setIcon(iconPlay);
        buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);
        labelRecordTime.setFont(new Font("Sans", Font.BOLD, 12));

        add(buttonRecord);
        add(labelRecordTime);
        add(buttonPlay);

        buttonRecord.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPlay.addActionListener(this);

        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    /**
     * Handle click events on the buttons.
     */
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        JButton button = (JButton) event.getSource();
        if (button == buttonRecord) {
            if (!isRecording) {
                startRecording();
            } else {
                stopRecording();
            }

        } else if (button == buttonPlay) {
            if (!isPlaying) {
                playBack();
            } else {
                stopPlaying();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start recording sound, the time will count up.
     */
    private void startRecording() {
        Thread recordThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    isRecording = true;
                    buttonRecord.setText("Stop");
                    buttonRecord.setIcon(iconStop);
                    buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);

                    recorder.start();

                } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(SwingSoundRecorder.this,
                            "Error", "Could not start recording sound!",
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        recordThread.start();
        timer = new RecordTimer(labelRecordTime);
        timer.start();
    }

    /**
     * Stop recording and save the sound into a WAV file
     */
    private void stopRecording() {
        isRecording = false;
        try {
            timer.cancel();
            buttonRecord.setText("Record");
            buttonRecord.setIcon(iconRecord);
            
            setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));

            recorder.stop();

            setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));

            saveFile();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(SwingSoundRecorder.this, "Error",
                    "Error stopping sound recording!",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start playing back the sound.
     */
    private void playBack() {
        timer = new RecordTimer(labelRecordTime);
        timer.start();
        isPlaying = true;
        playbackThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    buttonPlay.setText("Stop");
                    buttonPlay.setIcon(iconStop);
                    buttonRecord.setEnabled(false);

                    player.play(saveFilePath);
                    timer.reset();

                    buttonPlay.setText("Play");
                    buttonRecord.setEnabled(true);
                    buttonPlay.setIcon(iconPlay);
                    isPlaying = false;

                } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });

        playbackThread.start();
    }

    /**
     * Stop playing back.
     */
    private void stopPlaying() {
        timer.reset();
        timer.interrupt();
        player.stop();
        playbackThread.interrupt();
    }

    /**
     * Save the recorded sound into a WAV file.
     * 
     * @author Nam Ha Minh, source is <a href="https://www.codejava.net/coding/capture-and-record-sound-into-wav-file-with-java-sound-api">here</a>
     */
    private void saveFile() {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        FileFilter wavFilter = new FileFilter() {
            @Override
            public String getDescription() {
                return "Sound file (*.WAV)";
            }

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File file) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".wav");
                }
            }
        };

        fileChooser.setFileFilter(wavFilter);
        fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

        int userChoice = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this);
        if (userChoice == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            saveFilePath = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
            if (!saveFilePath.toLowerCase().endsWith(".wav")) {
                saveFilePath += ".wav";
            }

            File wavFile = new File(saveFilePath);

            try {
                recorder.save(wavFile);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(SwingSoundRecorder.this,
                        "Saved recorded sound to:\n" + saveFilePath);

                buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(SwingSoundRecorder.this, "Error",
                        "Error saving to sound file!",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

```
public class SoundRecordingUtil {
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
    private ByteArrayOutputStream recordBytes;
    private TargetDataLine audioLine;
    private AudioFormat format;

    private boolean isRunning;

    /**
     * Defines a default audio format used to record
     */
    AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
        float sampleRate = 44100;
        int sampleSizeInBits = 16;
        int channels = 2;
        boolean signed = true;
        boolean bigEndian = true;
        return new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits, channels, signed,
                bigEndian);
    }

    /**
     * Start recording sound.
     * @throws LineUnavailableException if the system does not support the specified 
     * audio format nor open the audio data line.
     */
    public void start() throws LineUnavailableException {
        format = getAudioFormat();
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);

        // checks if system supports the data line
        if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
            throw new LineUnavailableException(
                    "The system does not support the specified format.");
        }

        audioLine = AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(format);

        audioLine.open(format);
        audioLine.start();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int bytesRead = 0;

        recordBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        isRunning = true;

        while (isRunning) {
            bytesRead = audioLine.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
            recordBytes.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Stop recording sound.
     * @throws IOException if any I/O error occurs.
     */
    public void stop() throws IOException {
        isRunning = false;
        
        if (audioLine != null) {
            audioLine.drain();
            audioLine.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Save recorded sound data into a .wav file format.
     * @param wavFile The file to be saved.
     * @throws IOException if any I/O error occurs.
     * @throws UnsupportedAudioFileException 
     */
    public void save(File wavFile) throws IOException {
        byte[] audioData = recordBytes.toByteArray();
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(audioData);
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = new AudioInputStream(bais, format,
                audioData.length / format.getFrameSize());      
        AudioSystem.write(audioInputStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, wavFile);

        audioInputStream.close();
        recordBytes.close();
    }
}
```

```
public class RecordTimer extends Thread {
    private DateFormat dateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"); 
    private boolean isRunning = false;
    private boolean isReset = false;
    private long startTime;
    private JLabel labelRecordTime;
    
    RecordTimer(JLabel labelRecordTime) {
        this.labelRecordTime = labelRecordTime;
    }
    
    public void run() {
        isRunning = true;
        
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        while (isRunning) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                labelRecordTime.setText("Record Time: " + toTimeString());
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                if (isReset) {
                    labelRecordTime.setText("Record Time: 00:00:00");
                    isRunning = false;      
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Cancel counting record/play time.
     */
    void cancel() {
        isRunning = false;      
    }
    
    /**
     * Reset counting to "00:00:00"
     */
    void reset() {
        isReset = true;
        isRunning = false;
    }
    
    /**
     * Generate a String for time counter in the format of "HH:mm:ss"
     * @return the time counter
     */
    private String toTimeString() {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Date current = new Date(now - startTime);
        dateFormater.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        String timeCounter = dateFormater.format(current);
        return timeCounter;
    }
}
```

```
public class AudioPlayer implements LineListener {
    /**
     * this flag indicates whether the playback completes or not.
     */
    boolean playCompleted;
    
    /**
     * this flag indicates whether the playback is stopped or not.
     */
    boolean isStopped;

    /**
     * Play a given audio file.
     * 
     * @param audioFilePath
     *            Path of the audio file.
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws UnsupportedAudioFileException
     * @throws LineUnavailableException
     */
    void play(String audioFilePath) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException,
            IOException, LineUnavailableException {
        File audioFile = new File(audioFilePath);

        AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem
                .getAudioInputStream(audioFile);

        AudioFormat format = audioStream.getFormat();

        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);

        Clip audioClip = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);

        audioClip.addLineListener(this);

        audioClip.open(audioStream);

        audioClip.start();
        
        playCompleted = false;
        
        while (!playCompleted) {
            // wait for the playback completes
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                if (isStopped) {
                    audioClip.stop();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        audioClip.close();

    }

    /**
     * Stop playing back.
     */
    public void stop() {
        isStopped = true;
    }
    
    /**
     * Listens to the audio line events to know when the playback completes.
     */
    @Override
    public void update(LineEvent event) {
        LineEvent.Type type = event.getType();
        if (type == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
            playCompleted = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please paste the complete class code

Comment: Did you try to paste in `net.codejava.sound.SwingSoundRecorder` to the main class text field 'manually'?

Comment: @g00se You can't in Eclipse: there is a combo box that *should* show every Java class with a main method, you then select the one that is the main class of your project. I installed a second Eclipse just so I could have this one project as the only one in my workspace, and the combo box is empty.

Comment: Well i just tried it and you can in the version I tried it in (Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0)). I too found I couldn't browse to the correct main class. Perhaps the Eclipse metadata in their project files is incomplete… (I don't use IDEs when I can avoid it)

Comment: @g00se I created a new project and copied the classes of the first one in the second. Eclipse didn't see the main method of the second project, but it suddently saw the main method of the first one. I have no idea what happened...

Comment: Glad it's working. I would recommend using generic solutions, e.g. turn it into a Maven project that you can manipulate at the command line and then import that into Eclipse if you must